# Why does FormView (CBV) based view not have a URL parameter in context?

Tags: django

I have a class based view which needs to accept a Form submission. I am trying to auto-populate some of the form fields using the primary key within the URL path (e.g. /main/video/play/135). The class based view is based on FormView, the code I have makes the pk available in context if I use TemplateView, but that is not particularly good for handling forms.

urls.py

```
app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('video/<int:pk>', views.VideoDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('video/preview/<int:pk>', views.VideoPreview.as_view(), name='preview'),
    path('player', views.PlayerListView.as_view(), name='player_list'),
    path('video/play/<int:pk>/', views.VideoPlayView.as_view(), name='play'),
    path('', views.VideoListView.as_view(), name="video_list")
]
```

Relevant class from views.py:

```
class VideoPlayView(FormView):

    template_name = "main/video_play.html"
    form_class = VideoPlayForm
    initial = {}
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    def get_initial(self, **kwargs):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        #initial['video'] = pk
        initial['watch_date'] = datetime.date.today()
        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kc = kwargs.copy()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        video = Video.objects.get(context['pk'])
        context['video'] = video
        context['test'] = kc
        self.initial['video'] = video.pk
        context['viewers'] = Viewer.objects.all()
        context['players'] = Player.objects.filter(ready=True)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return HttpResponse("Done")
```

I get a key error at the line:

```
video = Video.objects.get(context['pk'])
```

Viewing the debug info on the error page indicates that the context does not have the pk value stored within it.

If I change the base class to TemplateView with a FormMixin I don't get this key error (but I do have problems POSTing the form data), so I know that the code is basically okay. My understanding is that the FormView class should populate context in the same way as the TemplateView class.

Any idea why FormView behaves this way, and how can I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `pk` from the URL, `self.kwargs['pk']` will work in all Django generic class-based-views.

In `TemplateView`, the [`get()`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/#get) method passes `kwargs` to the `get_context_data` method, so you can use `context['pk']`. The `FormView` [`get()`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/#get) method calls `get_context_data()` without passing any kwargs, so that won't work.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that `self.kwargs['pk']` in `get_initial`, `dispatch`, and `get_context_data` methods and it seems to work fine in all of them. It seems odd to me that the FormView's `get()` method doesn't pass any kwargs yet the TemplateView's does, do you know the reason behind this?

Comment: I think `TemplateView.get()` is the odd one out, not `FormView.get()` - for example `ListView.get()` and `DetailView.get()` do not pass any `**kwargs` to `get_context_data`. I don't know why `TemplateView` does this, but it is [documented behaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview). If you're really curious you could run `git blame` on the code and look at the related commits and tickets. In the view itself I would always stick to `self.kwargs['pk']` since that works in all generic class-based-views.